# check whether the user has a password set for his account in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, password, test

I'm writing a script and need to check $user if his account has a password set, how can I do this?

I know about this:

```
passwd --status username
```

> Display account status information. The status information consists of
>   7 fields. The first field is the user's login name. The second field
>   indicates if the user account has a locked password (L), has no
>   password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field gives the
>   date of the last password change. The next four fields are the minimum
>   age, maximum age, warning period, and inactivity period for the
>   password. These ages are expressed in days.

**but I need something that can fit in a `if test`**

Here is the code:

```
userPass()
{
    for i in "#@"
    do
        if [ "$i" = root ]
        then
            continue
        else
            echo "Changing password for $i:"
            echo $i:$i"YOURSTRONGPASSWORDHERE" | chpasswd
            if [ "$?" = 0 ]
            then
                echo "Password for user $i changed successfully"
            fi
        fi
    done
}
userPass $1 $2 $3
```

Comment: @SivaPrasath updated, it's was there in between all the info

Comment: @SivaPrasath yes, check if $user/accountt is missing a password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
if [ `passwd -S ${i} | cut -d" " -f2` == "P" ]; then do some stuff; fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the output of `passwd --status` indicates whether the user has no password ("has no password (NP)"), you can check that:

```
if [[ $(passwd --status "$i" | awk '{print $2}') = NP ]]
then
    echo "$i doesn't have a password."
fi
```

Or:

```
case $(passwd --status "$i" | awk '{print $2}') in
  NP)  echo "$i doesn't have a password."
       # set password here.
       ;;
  L)  echo "$i's account is locked." ;;
  P)  echo "$i has a password." ;;
esac
```

Comment: +1 for the second option....

Comment: The first option didn't work as expected and I had to add to it for it to work, don't have here what it was but there are other answers from `passwd --status that are not NP but still don't make a password set`

Comment: Whatever you say

Answer (score 2):

We can also check in `/etc/password` if we have access.

```
if [ `awk -F ':' '/^'$i':/ {print $2}' /etc/shadow` ] ; then 
   echo "User has passwd" ; 
else 
   echo "NO passwd";
fi
```